# Export a filtered view from PowerPivot into Excel

Tags: excel, extract, powerpivot

I don't have any concrete example but I have a PowerPivot table containing nearly 2 million lines. Users will work on it regularly and filter down until they get the data that they want. Filters will always change depending on the user and on the information that they are looking for.

My question is: is there a way to extract into a simple table or pivot table the information from the PowerPivot BUT the active filtered information only?

So let's say for example I have table1 containing 2 million rows. I apply different filters in the table to narrow it down to 10,000. Is there a way for me to extract those 10,000 rows specifically in a simple Excel table or pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is to **copy** the table, and paste into a Worksheet.

Right click the intersection of Row / Column Headers and select `Copy`:

[image: whole table context menu]

Only the visible filtered rows will be copied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! Ok, then depending on the number of rows, the process will be more or less slow.

I guess no way to do it via DAX query or else?